# newline not created on Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008

I'm working in C# on a development machine (Windows 8) and using the following code to append a line to a file:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter fs = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sFileName, true))
{
    fs.WriteLine(sLine);
}
```

This works perfectly fine in my development environment and every time creates a new line. However, when I deploy it to Windows Server 2008, it does not create a new line, it just appends to the existing line so after running several times I have one long line of data.

What happens differently between the two computers? Is there a setting I need to change on my server to get this to work right?

Thanks!

Comment: how did you create `sLine`, show that code.

Comment: sLine is read from another file using reader.ReadLine(). Why would that be relevant to how it is written and the difference between two operating systems on the WriteLine command?

Comment: That seems highly unlikely. Do you have a small, self-contained example that I can test? I've used `StreamWriter` on multiple versions of Windows, including Server 2008, and have never run into what you describe.

Comment: Apologies to the person who posted a solution earlier. The problem did appear to be solved by using Environment.NewLine. Unfortunately, my test referenced an earlier version that did not have that change. Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this should be a comment, but I don't have reputation.

I've got another suggestion, why don't you try using `File.WriteLine` instead of `StreamWriter.WriteLine`?

```
public void addText(string stringToAdd, string FilePath)
{
     System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(FilePath, new string[]{stringToAdd});
}
```

Comment: +1 for using `File.WriteAllLines()` , as it will take care of disposal.